# Cypher -Tally report on the depth of each relationship type stemming from parent node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create tally report on the depth of each relationship type stemming from parent node but I running into issues with the following error:

```
"Type mismatch: r already defined with conflicting type Relationship (expected Collection<Relationship>)
```

Here is the output I am attempting to achieve:

```
[
   {
      reltype    : "123A_RelationshipTitleOne",
      depthcount : 5
   }, {
      reltype    : "123A_RelationshipTitleTwo",
      depthcount : 9
   }, {
      reltype    : "123A_RelationshipTitleThree",
      depthcount : 42
   }
]
```

Here is my cypher query attempt that generates the error mentioned above. In place of '123A' I use a a variable but I used '123A' as a legible working example here:

```
MATCH (n {id: '123A'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
WHERE left( type(r), LENGTH( '123A' )) = '123A'
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(n)-[r*]->(c)
WITH n, COLLECT({
    id    : type(r),
    count : MAX(length(p))
}) AS leafreport
RETURN n, leafreport
```

I am very grateful for help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

The `type mismatch` error is being caused by using the bound variable `r` to represent first a relationship and then (in the second `OPTIONAL MATCH`) a Collection of relationships.

In the pattern `(n)-[r*]->(c)`, `r*` indicates a variable length path so `r` is bound to a Collection of relationships that match the variable length pattern. However `r` was previously bound to a relationship in `OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()`, thus the error. If you want to check that `r` is in the path, `p`, use a `WHERE` clause. Something like this:

```
MATCH (n {id: '123A'})
MATCH (n)-[r]-()
WHERE left( type(r), LENGTH( '123A' )) = '123A'
MATCH p=(n)-[rs*]->(c) WHERE r IN rs
WITH n, {
    id    : type(r),
    count : MAX(length(p))
} AS leafreport
RETURN n, leafreport
```

I don't think you want the second `OPTIONAL MATCH` to be optional, so I changed it to a `MATCH` clause

Comment: Thank you greatly for your help @William Lyon Though I am still running into problems. The second OPTIONAL MATCH is meant for the scenario where there are no relationships that fulfill WHERE left( type(r), LENGTH( '123A' )) = '123A'

Without the second OPTIONAL MATCH I get this error: "MATCH cannot follow OPTIONAL MATCH (perhaps use a WITH clause between them) 

With the second OPTIONAL MATCH, I get this error: Parameter maps cannot be used in MATCH patterns (use a literal map instead, eg. \\\"{id: {param}.id}\\\") (line 1, column 10 (offset: 9))\\n\\\"MATCH (n {_nodeid})

Comment: Instead of `MATCH (n {_nodeid})` you should use `MATCH (n {id: {_nodeid}})` where `_nodeid` is `{id: '123a'}`. That is causing the parameter maps error.

Comment: So do you want to use `OPTIONAL MATCH` at all then? Any piece of the pattern that doesn't match in an optional match will be `NULL` and piped through to the rest of the query. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: thnx - parameter maps error now solved - apologies for my typo. I see your  point now about OPTIONAL MATCH as I am now getting {"id":null,"count":null} for cases that do not support WHERE left( type(r), LENGTH( '123A' )) = '123A' But the only way to avoid the MATCH cannot follow OPTIONAL MATCH is to make the OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()

Comment: the query is running now regardless of the {"id":null,"count":null} issue but it is really really slow and it is returning a count of 4 instead of the two that is created from this query MATCH p=(n {id:'123a'})-[r:`123A_RelationshipTitleOne`*]->(c)
RETURN MAX(length(p))

Comment: I think you should change all `OPTIONAL MATCH` statements to `MATCH`. It's not clear to me why you want the `OPTIONAL MATCH`.

Comment: As for performance, your string comparison `left(type(r)...` is not supported by an index, also variable length paths are expensive. You should specify an upper bound or perhaps consider the `shortestPath` function. Finally consider using Node labels. In general see this [blog post](http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-2-query-tuning/) for [query performance issues](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-tuning.html).

Comment: I recently emptied my database and I now only have 180 nodes and 400 relationships. I tried with all MATCH instead of OPTIONAL MATCH and its still running pretty slow. I then tried to pull the WHERE left( type(r), LENGTH( {_nodeid} )) = {_nodeid} and then the  WHERE r IN rs and each time it still runs very slow