# Cypher LinkedList - how to get length?

Tags: arrays, neo4j, cypher

In continuation of a discussion related to a linkedlist serving as a workable array where each hop depth represents an index that can be ordered:

[CYPHER store order of node relationships of the same label when I create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263822/cypher-store-order-of-node-relationships-of-the-same-label-when-i-create/33267061#33267061)

[Cypher Linked LIst: how to unshift and replace by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306838/cypher-linked-list-how-to-unshift-and-replace-by-index)

[Cypher LinkedList Match by index but "Don't know how to compare that." instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447234/cypher-linkedlist-match-by-index-but-dont-know-how-to-compare-that-instead)

I have recently been trying to capture a report on each array that belong to a parent node. This report includes a unique relationshiptype and a count of how many elements are in the linked list array:

```
[
   {
      reltype    : "123A_RelationshipTitleOne",
      depthcount : 5
   }, {
      reltype    : "123A_RelationshipTitleTwo",
      depthcount : 9
   }, {
      reltype    : "123A_RelationshipTitleThree",
      depthcount : 42
   }
]
```

[Cypher -Tally report on the depth of each relationship type stemming from parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635241/cypher-tally-report-on-the-depth-of-each-relationship-type-stemming-from-parent)

We are close to a solution but the query time is very slow and the count amount is double its expected value.

On stackoverflow we have documented queries for array-like features of a linkedlist including unshift at the beginning, insert at index, replace at index, and push at the end of the "array"

I'm hoping for help on also the array length feature

I am very grateful for help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
MATCH p = (a:Head {id:234})-[:NEXT*..20]->(b:End)
RETURN max(length(path))
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
MATCH (n { id: '123A' })
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(n)-[r*]->(c)
WHERE (type(r[0]) STARTS WITH '123A') AND NOT (c)-->()
RETURN n, COLLECT({ id: type(r[0]), depth: length(p)}) AS leafreport;
```

The `NOT (c)-->()` test is for ensuring that the query only collects "complete paths", not partial paths. This presumes that in this use case every linked list ends with a node that has no outgoing relationships.

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=wjjj1v) that shows the results for some sample data.

Notes:

1. If `n` is not found, then no rows are returned.
2. If `n` is found, but there are no initial relationships whose types start with "123A", then `leafreport` will be `[{id:null, depth:null}]`.
3. The `x STARTS WITH '123A'` syntax was introduced in neo4j 2.3. In prior versions, you'd have to use a less readable regexp: `x =~ "123A.*"`.

Comment: thank you greatly for your help Cybersam - though I am still having trouble. In this zip I have included json output for two scenarios (one with 2 child nodes and another with 6 child nodes) seasidesyndication.com/cypher.zip The files marked initial are a result of MATCH ()-[r:`123A_Foo`]->() RETURN and the others are derivations of your query above.  The children from the first example (w/ 2children) have only the 123A_Foo relationship while the other example has children with multiple relationships. Both queries run relatively slow because I think the query is cycling over COLLECT too much

Comment: the 6 child node example normally hangs and the 2 child node example with your query returns a leafreport with 9 elements in the array instead of one item with [ {id: 123A_Foo, depth: 2} or {id: 123A_Foo, depth: 3}] found throughout